# UPSERT (insert or update) on a table with compound primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, upsert

I have the following table structure

```
'category_id', 'int(11)', 'PRI'
'page_id', 'int(11)', 'PRI'
'current_week_visits', 'int(11)'
```

I keep updating the current week visits daily on this table and I would like to insert a row if (app_id, page_id) is not present in the table. Else, update the current_week visits

I tried,

```
INSERT INTO visits (category_id, page_id, current_week_visits) VALUES (150, 1, 100) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE current_week_visits = current_week_visits + 100;
```

But it does not seem to save the current week visits. Could you throw some light on what's wrong here?

Comment: UPSERT? Is that what they call it when INSERT and UPDATE are dating?

Comment: @Barmar this is a valid term of art, although the more correct term would be `MERGE`

Comment: Your query works for me: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4712e/1

Comment: @vasa the query seems valid to me; do you have more details?

Comment: @vasa it also works perfectly for me. have you tried making an http://www.sqlfiddle.com ? see it working here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/68718/1/0

Comment: @vasa what version of mysql are you running?

Comment: SQLfiddle is awesome. I didn't know about it until now. My table had null values for current_week_visits. I truncated the table and tried it again and it worked. Thanks guys.

Comment: https://github.com/seamusabshere/upsert is a Ruby library (disclosure: mine) that transparently creates an upsert function and allows composite primary keys - in fact, the "selector" doesn't have to be indexed at all